# Изменение размера шрифта на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть элемент range:

```
<input id="seek" type="range" name="seekbar" step="3" min="8" max="24">
```

и элемент с текстом

```
<h3 id="output_client_text">Ваш текст</h3>
```

Как можно сделать что бы при изменении элемента range менялся размер шрифта?

Comment: А с чем у вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Нужно изменить размер шрифта заголовка с помощью элемента range. Думаю, это все что нужно знать)

Comment: Меняем значение range - меняется размер шрифта относительно значения range

Comment: По идее все эти элементарные основы описаны в любом учебнике по js. Если вы пршли сюда, значит или не читали никакой учебник вообще, или что-то в учебниках не поняли, и об этом нам тоже желательно знать. Впрочем, добрые люди и без этого уже поотвечали)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#seek').change(function(){
 var a = $(this).val();
  $('#output_client_text').css({
   'font-size': a+'px'
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="seek" type="range" name="seekbar" step="3" min="8" max="24">

<h3 id="output_client_text">Ваш текст</h3>
```

както так

Comment: а при чем тут jquery?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Cheg с ним проще роботать

Comment: @vov4ok с ним проще работать, когда он подключен и используется во всем проекте, а не только для такой простой задачи

Comment: Привет, я из 2023. У нас, чтобы поменять размер шрифта подымают ноду на кубах, на ней Next приложение, которое обслуживает кастомный инпут и по сокетам меняет размер шрифта текста, отрендереного на канвасе с использованием WebGL

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
var rng = document.getElementById('seek');
var text = document.getElementById('output_client_text');  
rng.addEventListener("input", 
  function() {            
    text.style.fontSize = rng.value + 'px'           
  });
```

Пример: 
https://jsfiddle.net/s4498wex/4/

Comment: Почему бы не найти целевой элемент единожды, чтобы не искать его заново при каждом изменении range?

Comment: @smellyshovel разумеется)

Answer (score 0):

1. Навешиваем обработчик события `change` на range.
2. В коллбэке изменяем стиль элемента.

   ```
   var range = document.querySelector("#seek"),
       h3 = document.querySelector("#output_client_text");

   range.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
       h3.style.fontSize = this.value + "px";
   });
   ```

Рабочий пример:

```js
var range = document.querySelector("#seek"),
    h3 = document.querySelector("#output_client_text");

range.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    h3.style.fontSize = this.value + "px";
});
```

```html
<h3 id="output_client_text">Ваш текст</h3>

<input id="seek" type="range" name="seekbar" step="3" min="8" max="24">
```

Comment: Что-то не могу код подсветить. Может быть поправит кто?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="999" oninput="fontS(this.value);">
<div id="hz">текст</div>
```

JS

```
function fontS(val){
document.getElementById("hz").style.fontSize=val+"px";
}
```